# change language ID in characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document that some chars (like "[") are in lang.charaters LanguageID=2057 and some LanguageID=1037

I tried to change it via the following code:

```
For Each oChr In pRange.Characters
         If oChr.LanguageID = 2057 Then
           oChr.LanguageID = 1037
         End If
Loop Until pRange Is Nothing
```

but the LanguageID is not changing after the assignment

Why ? how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a procedure I wrote a while back that changes the proofing language.

You are correct that the proofing language attribute can be applied to a character but you do not need to examine each character to reset. The following checks all stories of a document and sets the proofing language. You can change the constant to what you want instead of EnglishUS.

```
Sub ProofingLanguageEnglishUSAllStory()    ' based on field updater by Greg Maxey
    ' https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/word_fields.html
    ' Charles Kenyon 6 November 2018
    ' https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/force-all-documents-to-be-edited-in-uk-english/df6d1f8e-5426-49d9-bea0-5620d0208294
    ' Changes proofing language to English US in all stories of document
    ' Language IDs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdlanguageid
    Dim rngStory As Word.range
    Dim lngValidate As Long ' do not know purpose of this
    Dim oShp As Shape
    lngValidate = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).range.StoryType
    For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
      'Iterate through all linked stories
      Do
        On Error Resume Next
        rngStory.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS  ' delete or comment out if you do not want to change the language ID

        rngStory.NoProofing = False        Select Case rngStory.StoryType
          Case 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
            If rngStory.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
              For Each oShp In rngStory.ShapeRange
                If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                   ' Comment out or delete the next line if you do not want to change proofing language
                   oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS  ' delete or comment out if you do not want to change the language ID
                   ' Comment out or delete the next line if you do not want to change the "no proofing" setting
                   oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.NoProofing = False
                End If
              Next
            End If
          Case Else
            'Do Nothing
        End Select
        On Error GoTo -1
        'Get next linked story (if any)
        Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
      Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
      Next
End Sub
```

This is one of three macros on [the page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b) that deal with different problems. The macros use the Word constants for the language IDs rather than the numerical equivalents. This is my Article on the Microsoft Answers site on the topic: [Fixing Proofing Language Problems](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b).

Comment: the same ... the assign value to  rngStory.LanguageID is not working. before the rngStory.LanguageID=9999999 and the same value is after the assignment

Comment: Did you use this macro?  Did you use the vba Constant like EnglishUS in the macro or the numerical equivalent? Is there some reason you want to allow other variations on your Language 1037 so that if it were 1033 it would be OK?

Answer (score 0):

Work around:

```
 With Selection.Find
        .LanguageID = 3081
        .Text = "'"
        .Replacement.Text = "'"
        .Replacement.LanguageID = 1037
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
    End With
```